# Transactional Replication with Always On via Sql Server 2014

Tags: availability-groups, transactional-replication

My Scenario is given below...i want to configure transactional replication with alwayson and i know this is possible but my question is "I have two publisher sql server(SQL01_REPLICATION) is running on 32 bit operating system and one subscriber(64 bit) which is work as a primary for alwaysOn".so this is possible or not ?

1. SQL01_REPLICATION(32 bit os) as a PUBLISHER(sql server 2014 and window server 2008(32bit)).
2. SQL02_REPLICATION(32 bit os) as a PUBLISHER(sql server 2014 and window server 2008(32bit))..
3. SQL03_AG(64 bit os) as a PRIMARY REPLICA FOR AG AND SUBSCRIBER FOR                                REPLICATION(sql server 2014 and window server 2012(64bit))..
4. SQL04_AG(64 bit os) as a SECONDARY REPLICA FOR AG(sql server 2014 and window server 2012(64bit))..

According to above description of my existing server...i have a two publisher with 32 bit OS for replication and two server with 64 bit OS for AlwayOn Availability group.
my question is according to above description can i implement transactional replication with AlwaysOn.

Please advise me which technology is suitable for my current scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done like normal.

32/64 bit can replicate to each other (you wouldn't think so but they do and Microsoft has documented it on MSDN).

Also you can have an AG as a subscriber but you must use the name of the listener when setting it up. There's an MSDN article for this as well.

Comment: How to find out the MSDN article...can you please send me the link .and thanks for answer my question...

Comment: And i more thing...is all server are working under the same domain controller ? SQL01_REPLICATION
SQL02_REPLICATION
SQL03_AG(64 bit os)
SQL04_AG(64 bit os)

Comment: 1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2010/04/01/moving-data-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-sql-server-instances/

2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882436.aspx

And replication in general can use either AD or SQL logins and so the inter-domain stuff doesn't really matter.